# using gpio-keys interrupt to wake up screen on RPi3

Tags: android, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3, device-tree, wakeup

I am trying to use a **gpio-keys** interrupt to wake up the screen after it goes to sleep. I am using **Raspberry Pi 3** and **Lineage OS 14.1**. I have been able to successfully configure the gpio-keys where it registers input device events upon receiving an interrupt. However, I cannot get it to wake up the screen when it goes off. My device tree overlay file for my gpio-keys device is below:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

fragment@0 {
    // Configure the gpio pin controller
    target = <&gpio>;
    __overlay__ {
        pin_state: key_pins@0 {
            brcm,pins = <17>;       // gpio number
            brcm,function = <0>;    // 0 = input, 1 = output
            brcm,pull = <2>;        // 0 = none, 1 = pull down, 2 = pull up
        };
    };
};      

fragment@1 {    
    target-path = "/";
    __overlay__ {
        keypad: proximity@0 {
            compatible = "gpio-keys";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            key: proximity {
                label = "proximity detection";
                linux,code = <61>;          // F3 Key
                gpios = <&gpio 17 1>;       // GPIO 17
                wakeup-source;
            };
        };
    };
};
};
```

As you see in the file, I added the property **wakeup-source** but I believe perhaps it wakes up the system from a CPU sleep and not necessarily the screen itself when the screen is sleeping.

As you also see, my gpio-keys is tied to **KEY F3**. If I press F3 on the keyboard, it wakes up the monitor. However, if I generate an interrupt on the **GPIO17** pin, it doesn't wake up the monitor even though it registers as a KEY F3 event. Any suggestions as how to wake up the monitor from gpio-keys? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better solution than my previous answer. I'm leaving my previous answer as a post as it is a working solution (although it's not the most ideal solution).

Anyways, what you have to do is create (or modify) a **key layout** file. For this **key layout** file to register with a certain device, the **key layout** filename must follow a particular naming convention corresponding to details about the device you want to use (**gpio-keys** in my case). More details about this here: https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files. In my case, I decided for my **key layout** filename to match the device name. The device name in my case was **gpio-keys**, which you define in the device tree overlay file. You can also find the device name if you have access to an Android local terminal by typing into the command line `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`. A snippet of my gpio-keys overlay file is shown below:

```
fragment@1 {    
    target-path = "/";
    __overlay__ {
        keypad: gpio-keys {
            compatible = "gpio-keys";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            key: proximity {
                label = "proximity-detection";
                linux,code = <29>;      // KEY_LEFTCTRL
                linux,input-type = <1>;     // EV_KEY
                gpios = <&gpio 17 0>;       // GPIO 17
                wakeup-source;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

As you can see above next to **keypad:**, the device name **gpio-keys** is set. You can write other names here as well. Therefore, I named my key layout file **gpio-keys.kl**. I placed my **gpio-keys.kl** file in the **/system/usr/keylayout/** directory in Android. The **gpio-keys.kl** file is shown below:

```
# Key layout used for gpio-keys

key 29   CTRL_LEFT   WAKE
```

As my **gpio-key** (**GPIO17**) is tied to the **Linux keycode 29** or **KEY_LEFTCTRL**, my key layout file associates the **Linux keycode 29** (or **KEY_LEFTCTRL**) to the corresponding **Android keycode CTRL_LEFT**. Then I add the term **WAKE** on this same line as shown above. Linux keycodes and their matching Android keycodes can be found here: https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices.

This allows for my screen to wake when **GPIO17** receives an interrupt, as desired. This is a better solution than just using the Linux keycode for **WAKEUP** as you may want to write an Android app where you have several different **gpio-keys** that you want to treat differently. If each **gpio-key** is tied to a different keycode, you'll be able to distinguish them from each other. If they all have the same keycode, I think distinguishing between these different keys would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for proximity sensor functionalities. Linux already have  [linux,keycode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h) for this functionalities.

For proximity sensor you have to add the key code `0x0b (11)` in your device tree like:

```
 key: proximity {
                label = "proximity detection";
                linux,code = <11>; /* SW_FRONT_PROXIMITY */
            };
```

In similar way you can add the key code for other functionalities as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response vinod! But linux,code =<11> is also KEY_0. How would Linux distinguish between it being KEY_0 or SW_FRONT_PROXIMITY? Should I instead write linux,code =<0x0b>? Or does Linux execute both keys, etc?

Comment: There are a lot of keys which have same key code number. So Ideally based on the label and functionalities it will configure it only for proximity sensor.

Comment: So perhaps I should have the label read SW_FRONT_PROXIMITY? Let me give this a try and I'll get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. I did see the SW_FRONT_PROXIMITY key registering. I needed to specify the appropriate linux,input-type. However, I still have the same issue where it doesn't wake up the screen. I do see that my gpio-key is registered as a wakeup-source so not sure what the problem is. Again, perhaps wakeup-source refers to waking from CPU sleep but perhaps not monitor sleep.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it. I know this isn't the best way and I'm sure it's not the only way but this is how I finally got the screen to wake up upon my gpio receiving an interrupt.

I used keycode `143`, also known as `KEY_WAKEUP`. Device tree overlay snippet is shown below:

```
key: proximity {
            label = "proximity-detection";
            linux,code = <143>;          // KEY_WAKEUP
            gpios = <&gpio 17 0>;       // GPIO 17
            wakeup-source;
        };
```